# Can you deploy NodeJS REST API to Glassfish?

Tags: node.js, deployment

I am not experienced with servers in general, so be gentle. My question is: Is it possible to deploy an application made with Node and express to Glassfish server (where we currently already have angular dist folder) or is this impossible and i should deploy it separate for example with DigitalOcean.

Answer (score 0):

Glassfish is a server dedicated to running Java-based server (J2EE) applications. Nodejs applications (running Java**script**) must be deployed separately. You might be able to deploy your NodeJS application on the same host machine as your Glassfish server using a separate port. But the easiest thing would be to rent a server for the purpose from Digital Ocean or another cloud virtual-machine vendor.